# Why doesn't DrawThemeText work properly?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-styles

I'm trying to draw themed text on the window. However, instead of themed font, I always get something like bold MS Sans Serif w/o antialiasing. Why is it so?

---

**Edit:**

After applying mentioned changes, the code looks like this:

```
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX ctrl;
ctrl.dwSize = sizeof(ctrl);
ctrl.dwICC = ICC_TREEVIEW_CLASSES;
InitCommonControlsEx(&ctrl);
```

(...)

```
SetWindowTheme(mainWinHWND, L"explorer", nullptr);
```

(...)

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps); 

        HTHEME theme = OpenThemeData(hwnd, L"TREEVIEW");
        RECT rect;
        rect.left = 100;
        rect.top = 100;
        rect.right = 200;
        rect.bottom = 200;
        DrawThemeText(theme,
            hdc,
            TVP_TREEITEM,
            TREIS_NORMAL,
            L"Ala ma kota",
            11,
            DT_VCENTER | DT_LEFT,
            0,
            &rect);
        CloseThemeData(theme);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps); 
        return 0L; 
    }
```

The effect is still the same.

[image]

---

The whole code (~100 lines): http://pastebin.com/ZheZyrWy
Note, that it's only a proof-of-concept program and this is why I didn't include any error-checking. But DrawThemeText returns 0 (success).

Comment: `DT_VCENTER` has no effect when used as above. See [Format Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773199.aspx): _"`DT_VCENTER`: Centers text vertically. This value is used only with the `DT_SINGLELINE` value."_.

Comment: Ok; but that doesn't matter in this case - text is still drawn with a weird default font (I've tried passing 0 through flags as well)

Comment: Start by using treeview part and state ids instead of listview's.  Getting the common controls properly initialized would be a common failure mode as well, InitCommonControlsEx() as well as the required manifest to enable visual styles.  You are otherwise supposed to do this only when implementing custom drawing for an existing TreeView, no idea if this could work in an arbitrary paint message handler.

Comment: I included changes you mentioned, but with no effect. Notice, that both expand glyph and selection box were drawn correctly. I believe, that window class and theme class are two different things and that UXTheme.dll is responsible for loading a theme for treeview, not comctl32.dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are almost there, you are getting the Explorer theme style.  Just one wrong assumption, the theme for a treeview does *not* prescribe a font.  Quite visible in the .NET TreeView class for example, you can arbitrarily assign its Font property and you'll get the requested font.  And logically obvious, you didn't specify a font size anywhere so there's no reasonable way for the theming api to guess at a properly sized font.  Right now you are just getting the default font that's selected in the device context.

You *have* to select the font you want to use.